# Remove entire row if in a second column there is a floating number using bash

Tags: bash

This is my space delimited file:

```
bob.txt 32.1 0.99 34 56
ann.txt 35 45 23 45
```

I would like to remove all rows having a floating number in the second column, so the output is:

```
ann.txt 35 45 23 45
```

I tried to use grep, but I do not know how too specify the column in which it should look:

```
grep -vE '\-?[0-9]+|\-?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+' file.txt > out.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk:

```
 awk 'NR==1 || $2 !~ /^[[:digit:]]+[.][[:digit:]]+$/ { print }' file
```

Search for all lines where the second space delimited field does not have a pattern that matches one or more digits, a space and one or more digits and print the result.

Comment: I've amended the answer

Comment: sorry I deleted the comment because it does save the header as well :) thanks a lot!

Comment: Great. If it meets your needs, please accept the solution as an answer

Answer (score 1):

> how too specify the column in which it should look:

Match the first first column with a regex.

```
  grep -vE '^[^ ]+ +-?[0-9]+\.'
```

Comment: I tried, but I still have rows with floating numbers in the second column.

Comment: och, second, not third?

Comment: so it should be `grep -vE '^[^ ]+ +-?[0-9]+\.'`, no?